# Awk Greater Than Less Than

Tags: awk

I am using this command

```
num1=2.2
num2=4.5

result=$(awk 'BEGIN{print ($num2>$num1)?1:0}')
```

This always returns 0. Whether num2>numl or num1>num2
But when I put the actual numbers as such

```
result=$(awk 'BEGIN{print (4.5>2.2)?1:0}')
```

I would get a return value of 1. Which is correct.

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: @potong that would only work for integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it fails when you use variables is because the `awk` script enclosed by single quotes is evaluated by `awk` and not `bash`: so if you'd like to pass variables you are using from `bash` to `awk`, you'll have to specify it with the `-v` option as follows:

```
num1=2.2
num2=4.5

result=$(awk -v n1=$num1 -v n2=$num2 'BEGIN{print (n2>n1)?1:0}')
```

**Note**  that program variables used inside the `awk` script must not be prefixed with `$`

Comment: Thank you, I attempted this form as well but instead add $n2 and $n1 which does not work. Thanks again for another answer

Comment: "awk shell"??? awk is not shell, just like C is not shell. You wouldn't expect to be able to access the value of shell variables in a C program you call from shell and nor should you expect to in an awk program you call from shell.

Comment: thanks, it's just that so many people seem to think awk IS shell and that leads to confusion over syntax and variables so it's important to make the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$num1` and `$num2` are not expanded by bash -- you are using single quotes. The following will work, though:

```
result=$(awk "BEGIN{print ($num2>$num1)?1:0}")
```

Note, however, as pointed out in the comments that this is poor coding style and mixing bash and awk. Personally, I don't mind such constructs; but in general, especially for complex things and if you don't remember what things will get evaluated by bash when in double quotes, turn to the other answers to this question.

See the excellent example from @EdMorton below in the comments.

EDIT: Actually, instead of awk, I would use `bc`:

```
$num1=2.2
$num2=4.5

result=$( echo "$num2 > $num1" | bc )
```

Why? Because it is just a bit clearer... and lighter.

Or with Perl (because it is shorter and because I like Perl more than awk and because I like backticks more than `$()`:

```
result=`perl -e "print ( $num2 > $num1 ) ? 1 : 0;"`
```

Or, to be fancy (and probably inefficient):

```
if [ `echo -e "$num1\n$num2" | sort -n | head -1` != "$num1" ] ; then result=0 ; else result=1 ; fi
```

(Yes, I know)

I had a brief, intensive, 3-year long exposure to awk, in prehistoric times. Nowadays bash is everywhere and can do loads of stuff (I had sh/csh only at that time) so often it can be used instead of awk, while computers are fast enough for Perl to be used in ad hoc command lines instead of awk. Just sayin'.

Comment: No, absolutely do NOT do either of those things. Google for why.

Comment: @EdMorton -- you mean code injection using the variables? Well, in a setting where variables are tainted one should probably not use awk at all.

Comment: Nothing to do with variables being tainted, they could have exactly the values you want them to and still screw you up, plus with the double-quoted version you then have to escape other characters in your script like $s and backslashes and it quickly becomes a mess. Finally if your script grows to the point where you want to put it in a file for execution using -f, you then simply can't jump back and forth to shell. You should just never do it.

Comment: Well, yeah, mixing two languages like that is not precisely the highest point of coding etiquette. However, I would never say never and I think it is good enough here. Yes, I'm a Perl coder.

Comment: Here's a trivial example: a program designed to print the contents of a shell variable is `awk "BEGIN{print $shellvar}"`. Call it after setting `shellvar="3"` and it will output 3 as expected, but call it after setting `shellvar="c"` and it will print a blank line. Now change the script to `awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" 'BEGIN{ print awkvar}'` and it will print 3 and c respectively as expected both times. No tainted variables involved.

Comment: Ah. I have already forgotten why I haven't been using awk for the past ten years, thanks for a kindly reminder.

Comment: It's not an awk problem, it's a programmer problem. I'm sure there are many ways a programmer can shoot himself in the foot with perl, C, whatever. I know I said "never" but there actually are some very rare situations where jumping back-and-forth between shell and awk has some advantages, this just isn't an appropriate use of that functionality.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this in Perl? If so please share I would be interested in know how to do so.

Comment: @jenglee nah, I was just trolling. Well, actually, if I had to compare to floats in bash, I would use... see the EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
result=$(awk -v num1=2.2 -v num2=4.5 'BEGIN{print (num2 > num1) ? 1 : 0}')
```

See :

```
man awk | less +/'^ *-v'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
result=$(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$num2'>'$num1')?1:0}')
```

Think of the `'`'s as like poking holes through the `awk` command to the underlying `bash` shell.

Comment: ...and then think long and hard about the implications of that to your script and then don't do it. See the discussion I just had with January in this same thread.